# Check If Two Rhombus Overlap In Java

Tags: java, object, math, methods

I need to Check If Two Rhombus Overlap In Java, i dont understand how to do it properly

```
public class Rhombus {
    int p1;
    int p2;
    int p3;
    int p4;
    Rhombus(int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4){
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.p3 = p3;
        this.p4 = p4;
    }
    void overlaps(Rhombus r){
        System.out.println("Checking if one rhombus intersects the second one:");
        if (r.p1 == this.p1 || r.p1 == this.p2 || r.p1 == this.p3 || r.p1 == this.p4 || r.p2 == this.p1 || r.p2 == this.p2 || r.p2 == this.p3 || r.p2 == this.p4 || r.p3 == this.p1 || r.p3 == this.p2 || r.p3 == this.p3 || r.p3 == this.p4 || r.p4 == this.p1 || r.p4 == this.p2 || r.p4 == this.p3 || r.p4 == this.p4 ) System.out.println("true");
        else System.out.println("false");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rhombus rhombus1 = new Rhombus(3, 3, 3, 3);
        Rhombus rhombus2 = new Rhombus(1, 5, 5, 5);
        rhombus1.overlaps(rhombus2);
    }
}
```

I try this, but it doesnt work if one point cross another rhombus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void overlaps(Rhombus r) {
        int x1 = Math.min(this.p1, Math.min(this.p2, Math.min(this.p3, this.p4)));
        int y1 = Math.min(this.p1, Math.min(this.p2, Math.min(this.p3, this.p4)));
        int x2 = Math.max(this.p1, Math.max(this.p2, Math.max(this.p3, this.p4)));
        int y2 = Math.max(this.p1, Math.max(this.p2, Math.max(this.p3, this.p4)));
        int x3 = Math.min(r.p1, Math.min(r.p2, Math.min(r.p3, r.p4)));
        int y3 = Math.min(r.p1, Math.min(r.p2, Math.min(r.p3, r.p4)));
        int x4 = Math.max(r.p1, Math.max(r.p2, Math.max(r.p3, r.p4)));
        int y4 = Math.max(r.p1, Math.max(r.p2, Math.max(r.p3, r.p4)));

        if (x1 < x4 && x2 > x3 && y1 < y4 && y2 > y3) {
            System.out.println("One rhombus intersects the other");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The two rhombuses do not intersect");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not make eight multi dimensional arrays representing each of the eight sides total of the two rhombus , each of the elements represents a pixel along the edge of the rhombus and stores an array of two elements being x position of pixel and y position of pixel.
The use one of the two to loop over all it's elements of each side and find if any pixel pair get an exact match of the other quadrilateral pixel pair.
Personally, I think you would be better drawing some test cases to see if you can figure probability first by checking the positions along x and along y of the quadrilaterals four points to be better able to choose which side array to work on testing first.